# $A$ is a $12\times12$ matrix such that $A^{10 }=I$, and $\operatorname{rank}(A-I)=5$. How can we show $\operatorname{rank}(A^2 +A+I)\leq 7$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

If $A$ is a $12\times12$ matrix such that $A^{10 }=I$, and $\operatorname{rank}(A-I)=5$, how can we show that $\operatorname{rank}(A^2 +A+I)\leq 7$?

Comment: @amWhy you have turned the question into a nonsense.

Comment: I fixed the errors @ancientmathematician . Good catch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can't because it isn't.  The eigenvalues of $A$ are $10$'th roots of $1$.  The roots of $\lambda^2+\lambda+1$ are primitive cube roots of $1$.  So $A^2+A+I$ is nonsingular and has rank $12$.

Comment: Sorry for asking a rather annoying question, I can see that the eigenvalues of $A$ are 10th roots of unity, and the roots of the polynomial would be complex, but how does it relate to the fact that $A^{2} + A + I$ is non-singular?

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial, the eigenvalues of $p(A)$ are $p(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ runs over the eigenvalues of $A$.  In order for $p(A)$ to be singular, it needs to have $0$ as an eigenvalue, so some eigenvalue of $A$ must be a root of $p$.